# Program that automatically does ipconfig/release and then ipconfig/renew on a timer

Tags: windows, networking, cmd, ipconfig

As the title says, I want to create a program that automatically does ipconfig/release and then ipconfig/renew, every few minutes. I usually do this in the command prompt, but it would be much more convenient if a program could automate this. I was just wondering where I could even begin to create this program? Or is it impossible to automate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**untested** and likely incomplete for a .cmd file that can be called at startup or login or by task scheduler.  It will need administrator rights.

```
@echo off

:infiniteloop
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
timeout /t 200
goto :infiniteloop
```